# Store User entered hyperlinks within text

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

basically the user can make a post within which they can leave a comment . I want to allow my users to post something like : "This is a comment where aboutme is a hyperlink."
The aboutme word would be a clickable hyperlink but I have no clue how I store this . 
Currently I'm storing the comments in a mysql dB .

If I want to store the links separately to the comment how would I make the word aboutme have a hyperlink.

WordPress allows users to post paragraphs with hyperlinks within them this is a similar thing to what I'm looking to do.

Comment: after get data form DB, and before display make posprocess by replacing `aboutme` with valid link

Comment: Imagine 100 links and 100 comments , how does my application know which link belongs to which word in a comment

Comment: Oh my God! What a quantity! How can you deal with such small things? You must process every comment separately.

Comment: `strtr($comment_str, ['aboutme' => '< a href="/aboutme">aboutme</a>','foo'=>'Achmed: I will kill you']);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is a good idea but one way you can do this is to collect the link with the comment's content together...then, when showing the comment, you hunt down the links and display them accordingly.

So for instance, if the comments are displayed with `$comment->body` then you can process all the html tags with `{!!$comment->body !!}`

Another way might be, you collect the links separately, by the side of the comment box, that way at least you can easily validate the submitted links.